# npm: not found on jenkins agent, but available through ssh

Tags: linux, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set up a jenkins pipeline that utilizes multiple agents.  The agents are ubuntu instances living in a cloud tenancy (openstack).  When trying to run some `npm` commands on some of the instances, I am getting the error `npm: not found`.  I've read multiple other threads, but I am struggling to understand why npm might not be found.  I set these instances up myself, and I know I installed all requirements, including node and npm.

Let's say I have 2 nodes - `agent1` at IP1, and `agent2` at IP2.  They both have a user login with username `cooluser1`.  When I do an `ssh cooluser1@IP1` or `ssh cooluser1@IP2`, in either case, running `npm -v` gives me a proper node version (6.14.13).  However, in my pipeline, `npm` is not found in the IP2 instance.  Here's my pipline script:

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'agent1'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build'){
            steps {
                sh 'hostname -I'
                sh 'echo "$USER"'
                sh 'echo "$PATH"'
                sh 'npm -v'
            }
        }
        stage ('Run Tests'){
            parallel {
                stage('Running tests in parallel') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'agent2'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'hostname -I'
                        sh 'echo "$USER"'
                        sh 'echo "$PATH"'
                        sh 'npm -v'
                    }
                }
                stage {
                    // more stuff running on another agent (agent3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in both the main agent `agent1`, and in the parallel stages, I run the same code, which checks the host IP, the username, the path, and the `npm` version.  The IPs are as expected - IP1 and IP2.  The $USER in both cases is indeed `cooluser1`.  The path looks something like this:

```
// agent1
+ echo 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

// agent2
+ echo 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

A bit strange, but identical in both cases.

However, when I get to `npm --v`, for `agent1`, I get a version number, and any npm commands I want to run are workoing.  but in `agent2`, I get `npm: not found`, and the pipeline fails if I try to use any npm commands.  The full error is here:

```
+ npm -v
/home/vine/workspace/tend-multibranch_jenkins-testing@tmp/durable-d2a0251e/script.sh: 1: /home/vine/workspace/tend-multibranch_jenkins-testing@tmp/durable-d2a0251e/script.sh: npm: not found
```

But I clearly saw with `ssh cooluser1@IP2` that `npm` is available in that machine to that user.

What might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will propose to you to install nodejs plugin, configure any nodejs version you want in 'manage jenkins' -> 'global tools configurations' and set nodejs in pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    nodejs 'NodeJS_14.17.1'
  }
  stages {
    stage ('nodejs test') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm -v'
      }
    }
  }
}
```